# Posting a form into a new tab - Chrome extension

Tags: html, forms, post, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to post a form from my Chrome extension popup. When you click post the new tab opens but the data is not posted, after testing the same code in a normal page it worked perfectly. Is there something that restricts extensions from posting data via a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked it out, I was posing to jsFiddle and was using this url.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/mootools/1.3
```

This coincidentally does not work. You have to have a trailing `/` like so.

```
http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/mootools/1.3/
```

I am not quite sure why I think it is just the way that jsFiddles url structure is implemented.

So yeah, in short. Chrome extensions work fine, you just have to add a trailing `/` when posting to jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set [permissions](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions) for the url you try to post to?

Comment: Yes I had, I have got it now though, it was the URL I was posting to, it had to end with a `/`, I am not quite sure why. So it was not down to the extension it was down to the URL I was posting to. Should I delete the question, it is very specific.

Comment: @Wolfy please provide an answer with a little detail (a paragraph) about the solution, and you can select it as an answer.  I'm sure someone somewhere will encounter this issue again, and your answer will help them.